# updating symfony 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

im trying to update symfony 2.6 to 2.7

i've changed in my composer.json to 2.7 version

```
"symfony/symfony": "2.7.*"
```

im running

```
composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies
```

and getting this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.41
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.40
    ........
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.1
    - don't install symfony/asset v3.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0|remove symfony/asset v3.4.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v2.7.0|don't install symfony/asset v3.4.4
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.7.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2
, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v
2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/asset (locked at v3.4.4) -> satisfiable by symfony/asset[v3.4.4].
```

i dont understand what it wants from me

here is my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {


 "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.3.1",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "dev-master",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "~2.6",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "ircmaxell/password-compat": "^1.0",
    "helios-ag/fm-elfinder-bundle": "~5",
    "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^3.0",
    "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.4",
    "google/apiclient": "~2.0",
    "masih/youtubedownloader": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
        "component-dir": "web/assets"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

i've updated symfony/assets separately but it did not help
also tried updating  sensio/framework-extra-bundle and vich/uploader-bundle
which are referencing the symfoy/asset bundle 
this also did not help

Comment: Some of your dependencies aren't compatible with 2.7 and will need to also be updated. Have you tried a `composer update`?

Comment: @ceejayoz i've tried composer update but i dont know why its trying to update symfony to version 4

Comment: what does `composer why symfony/asset` say? maybe something in there you're not aware about?

Comment: I have found that debugging these sorts of things to be very challenging.  Adding the -vvv option might give you some more useful info.  But I usually end up just making a fresh project and installing the dependencies one by one.  And assuming the process completes then I replace the old composer.json with the new one.  And be sure to run composer self-update as well.

Comment: @Joe vich/uploader-bundle  1.4.2  requires  symfony/asset (^2.3|^3.0)

Comment: Useful as always these composer messages... asset 3.4.4 itself doesn't have much requirements except php version 5.5 or  >=7.0.8 if you meet those if those are met i'd try to require asset 3.4.4 manually and see if the error points to something more useful then. Otherwise Cerads suggestions always worked for me in those cases too.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: is there any reason not to update to Symfony 2.8 directly? This is also near the end of life, but has at least six more months of support

Comment: @NicoHaase 2.8 needs forms rewriting and other code fixes. dont have time for that now. i actually only needed the 2.7 because i had issues with swiftmailer bundle. did not send emails via smtp. but with 2.7 everything works fine :) but someday i will update my project to 2.8 and above

Answer (score 3):

thanks for the comments

i've installed clean symfony 2.7

based on previous `composer why symfony/asset`
that told me `vich/uploader-bundle 1.4.2 requires symfony/asset (^2.3|^3.0)`

i added it first with `composer require vich/uploader-bundle`
it automatically added version ^0.14.0

i've copied it to my composer and updated only it 
`composer update vich/uploader-bundle --with-dependencies`

and after that changed symfony version to 2.7 and updated 
`composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies`

everything worked fine :)

Comment: If you want instant upgrades of PHP code, checkout [RectorPHP](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector)

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  Just be aware that some of the other versions look a bit suspicious as well.  Might encounter other issues as well.  So consider rebuilding the composer.json file completely just to get a good start.